# esp8266 run downloaded binary in background

Tags: esp8266, background-task

Synopsis:

All of my devices based on ESP8266 / 32 (i have ~1000 of them) are reading sensors, doing some edge  computing and sending data back to a central server.

Most of the time however they are idling.

So i am thinking if following scenario is possible:

1. I write a library that polls for a task from a server
2. If a task is found, the task is downloaded
3. The task is run in background on ESP (background to the main loop logic)
4. When task is completed data is sent out back to the task-server

The question is around point 3.

Is it possible to 'run' a separate bin file (let's say from SPIFFS) in background similarly to linux :

```
 pid_t pid = fork();
 execv
```

If not (i guess it's not), is there any other option you can think of? (Like a background task) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP8266 is a pretty simple processor. Linux `fork()` has a whole lot of hardware support to give processes isolated address spaces and support preemptive multitasking. The ESP8266 doesn't have the hardware support to do this and the OSs it runs don't have a process model. So however you do this, you're not going to be using `fork()`.

If you're using the Arduino SDK then you're also using the ["Non-OS" SDK](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK), which the Arduino SDK is built on. The Non-OS SDK doesn't even have any internal concept of tasks or co-routines. So if you're using the Arduino SDK or any other SDK that's built on the Non-OS SDK, you'll need to implement your own "background" processing.

In the Arduino SDK, you'd rewrite your `loop()` code so that it would check if there's normal, foreground work, handle that, and then do a certain amount of background work. You'll need to decide how much background work you can do before you get back to the foreground work. And you'll also need to make sure the background work calls `yield()` or `delay()` once in a while so that the watchdog timer won't fire.

It's not going to be pretty.

So your code might look something like:

```
#define ELAPSED_WORK_TIME (millis() - work_start_time)

// maximum milliseconds before we must check if there's foreground work
// or yield() to keep the watchdog timer happy
#define MAX_WORK_TIME  1000

void loop() {
  while(foreground_work_is_available()) {
    do_foreground_work();
    yield();
  }

  if(background_work_is_available()) {
    unsigned long work_start_time = millis();

    do_some_work();

    if(ELAPSED_WORK_TIME > MAX_WORK_TIME)
      return;

    do_some_more_work();

    if(ELAPSED_WORK_TIME > MAX_WORK_TIME)
      return;
  }
}
```

Or if you can be sure that chunks of your background code won't run for too long you could use a state variable in the loop and when you run a chunk of the background code, set the state variable to indicate the next chunk to run and return to allow `loop()` to continue.

Something like this:

```
#define STATE_CHUNK1 1
#define STATE_CHUNK2 2
#define STATE_CHUNK3 3
#define STATE_CHUNK4 4

void loop() {
  static int background_work_state = STATE_CHUNK1;

  while(foreground_work_is_available()) {
    do_foreground_work();
    yield();
  }

  switch(loop_state) {
    case STATE_CHUNK1:
      work_chunk1();
      background_work_state = STATE_CHUNK2;
      return;

    case STATE_CHUNK2:
      work_chunk2();
      background_work_state = STATE_CHUNK3;
      return;

    case STATE_CHUNK3:
      work_chunk3();
      background_work_state = STATE_CHUNK3;
      return;

    case STATE_CHUNK4:
      work_chunk4();
      background_work_state = STATE_CHUNK4;
      return;
   }
}
```

You can make the state machine a lot more sophisticated if you need to. Maybe `work_chunk2()` can fail and you'll want to go back to `work_chunk1()` next time - then you'd test its return value to decide whether to set `background_work_state` to `STATE_CHUNK1` or `STATE_CHUNK3`.

There is another SDK for the ESP8266 called the ["RTOS" SDK](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK) - Realtime OS - docs for it [here](https://www.espressif.com/en/content/esp8266-rtos-sdk-api-reference). It might be better suited for doing what you want to do. You still won't be able to use `fork()` or preemptive multitasking with it, but it's much more asynchronous and has a programming model that allows you to break down your code into separate tasks which it will run for you. The downside is that it's much more complicated and less well documented than the Arduino environment and you'd almost certainly have to completely rewrite your existing code to use it.

Comment: Thanks John, i haven't heard about the RTOS yet. The way you have presented it, is +- exactly what i am trying to 'proof concept' now. So far i have managed to connect my ESP8266 to the grid library (already in use).

Do you know if i can 'run' a compiled .bin file somehow out of the ESP8266 code?

Let's say i have stored a test.bin on SPIFFS, is there (by any chance) any option to run it?

Comment: @PeeS I can't see any way to use two binaries at the same time. The Non-OS SDK is linked into the binary - there's no underlying OS running on the ESP. So you'd have two sets of everything, and contention for hardware resources like timers and the SPI hardware. Sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for your answers.